# Can I drag a document window to an email message to attach it?

Tags: macos, mail.app, automator, services

I realize that I can drag files from Finder and drop them in a mail message in Mail.app to attach them. What I would like to do is drag an active document window from another application, say Preview, into an mail message I am composing? I don't want to have to open a finder window and navigate to the correct folder and drag and drop from there.

I suppose the next best thing would be to have a service that could do this. Excel 2011 has a service available to attach the current document to a new email. This would be ok, although I'd like to have the ability to attach to the currently active email. Another problem, this service is not universally available (Preview does not have it, and this would be my most frequent app to do this from).

I guess the next best thing would be to have a quick ability to show the active document in Finder - whether this is from a universally available service, or perhaps an automator app that I could leave on my Dock.

Running Lion, 10.7.2, Mail.app Version 5.1 (1251/1251.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the little icon in the title bar of the document window and drag it into the message window in Mail. Works for Preview documents and should work for most, if not all, applications.

Comment: And don't forget to save first, if applicable.